# How to get all comments (including replies) using Graph API for page feed?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I call Graph API as

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?access_token={TOKEN}&filter=stream&fields=parent.fields(id),message,from&ids={PAGE_CONTAINING_EMBEDDED_FB_COMMENT_BOX}
```

the results displays the replies as well with "parent" field.

Trying the same for page feeds like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}/feed?access_token={TOKEN}&limit=100&fields=parent.fields(id)
```

I get the "Subfields are not supported by parent" error message.
What is the correct syntax of "fields=" parameter to retrieve all comments with replies for page posts?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get posts and replies, try this:

```
fields=from,to,message,picture,link,name,caption,description,created_time,updated_time,likes,comments.limit(999)
```

To get posts, replies and replies to replies, try this:

```
fields=from,to,message,link,name,caption,description,created_time,updated_time,likes,comments{from,to,message,link,name,caption,description,created_time,updated_time,like_count,comments{from,to,message,link,name,caption,description,created_time,updated_time,like_count}}
```